# MySql SELECT AVG of CASE statement Group Error

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, case, average

I am trying to populate a single average based off a `CASE` statement utilizing a `WHERE` clause with `MONTHS` of a `COUNT`, however it is returning an invalid use of group function Error Code 1111:

```
SELECT 
count(ORDER_NUMBER) as cnt,
a.ITEM,
MONTH(TRANS_DATE) as Month,
AVG(CASE
WHEN count(ORDER_NUMBER) IS NULL THEN 0
WHEN count(ORDER_NUMBER) < 1 AND a.CAT != 'E' THEN 0
WHEN count(ORDER_NUMBER) < 1 AND a.CAT = 'E' THEN .05
WHEN count(ORDER_NUMBER) >= 1 AND count(ORDER_NUMBER) < 4 AND a.CAT = 'E' THEN .5
WHEN count(ORDER_NUMBER) >= 4 AND a.CAT = 'E' THEN 1
WHEN count(ORDER_NUMBER) <= 5 AND a.CAT != 'E' THEN .05
WHEN count(ORDER_NUMBER) >= 6 AND count(ORDER_NUMBER) < 11 AND a.CAT != 'E' THEN .25
WHEN count(ORDER_NUMBER) >= 11 AND count(ORDER_NUMBER) < 21 AND a.CAT != 'E' THEN .5
WHEN count(ORDER_NUMBER) >= 21 AND a.CAT != 'E' THEN 1 END) as TSCORE
FROM trx.TRX_Import t2
    JOIN ATTRIBUTES a
    ON a.ITEM = t2.ITEM
WHERE `TRANS_DATE` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 365 DAY) AND CURDATE()
AND t2.ITEM = 'WARI-BB150'
```

When I add the additional `GROUP BY MONTH` It correctly identifies  each months TSCORE...I would rather it just spit out one AVERAGE of all those TSCORES.

With `GROUP BY MONTH`, it spits out:

```
   cnt     ITEM        Month   TSCORE
    1   WARI-BB150      1       0.5
    2   WARI-BB150      2       0.5
    1   WARI-BB150      3       0.5
    2   WARI-BB150      4       0.5
    2   WARI-BB150      5       0.5
    2   WARI-BB150      6       0.5
    4   WARI-BB150      7       1
    2   WARI-BB150      10      0.5
    3   WARI-BB150      11      0.5
    1   WARI-BB150      12      0.5
```

I would prefer the data to spit out just the average TSCORE of an item based of the above table (so only 1 row of info):

```
cnt   ITEM          TSCORE
20    WARI-BB150     0.55
```

Comment: You are trying to use `COUNT(*)` within `AVG()`.  To do that you need two queries, possibly one nested inside the other, possibly as a join on a sub-query.  *[You can't aggregate an aggregate within a single query.]*  If you supply example input data and example desired results then we may be able to recommend solutions.

Comment: This makes sense, from what I know I believe I have to use a subquery probably in the FROM..ie. (`SELECT AVG(avg_TSCORE) FROM (SELECT CASE avg_TSCORE WHEN ...`)

Comment: Bingo, I got it using what you have provided with a subquery, see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to use a subquery in the `FROM` clause and create an `AVG` on that:

```
SELECT
t2.ITEM as Item,
AVG(t2.TSCORE) as AvgTSCORE
FROM 
(SELECT count(ORDER_NUMBER) as cnt, t3.ITEM, MONTH(TRANS_DATE) as Month, 
(CASE
WHEN count(ORDER_NUMBER) IS NULL THEN 0
WHEN count(ORDER_NUMBER) < 1 AND a.CAT != 'E' THEN 0
WHEN count(ORDER_NUMBER) < 1 AND a.CAT = 'E' THEN .05
WHEN count(ORDER_NUMBER) >= 1 AND count(ORDER_NUMBER) < 4 AND a.CAT = 'E' THEN .5
WHEN count(ORDER_NUMBER) >= 4 AND a.CAT = 'E' THEN 1
WHEN count(ORDER_NUMBER) <= 5 AND a.CAT != 'E' THEN .05
WHEN count(ORDER_NUMBER) >= 6 AND count(ORDER_NUMBER) < 11 AND a.CAT != 'E' THEN .25
WHEN count(ORDER_NUMBER) >= 11 AND count(ORDER_NUMBER) < 21 AND a.CAT != 'E' THEN .5
WHEN count(ORDER_NUMBER) >= 21 AND a.CAT != 'E' THEN 1 END) as TSCORE
FROM trx.TRX_Import t3
JOIN ATTRIBUTES a
    ON a.ITEM = t3.ITEM
WHERE `TRANS_DATE` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 365 DAY) AND CURDATE()
AND t3.ITEM = 'WARI-BB150'
GROUP BY MONTH
) t2
```

Spits out:

```
Item         AvgTSCORE
WARI-BB150   0.55000
```